# Why does this JS function run upon clicking on a button, but not when called within another function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-apps-script, web-applications

The function I'm primarily running `savePo()` saves the html page input data into a spreadsheet and it works fine.
If I add `savefile()` to the bottom of the function, I see that it gets run, but it doesn't save the pdf file to the destination.
If I run this function directly (button click), it runs normally. What am I missing?

**Function saving form data to a spreadsheet**

```
function savePo(user) {
  //...gets html page input data and builds a 2D array, which gets saved in a Spreadsheet
  google.script.run
    .withFailureHandler(function (e) {
      alert("The PO could not be saved./No se pudo guardar el pedido. " + e);
    })
    .savePoData(poData, poOrigin);

  savefile(); //How to run this function, which is detailed below

  //Hides Order Po Header Field and its label
  document.getElementById("selectOrderPo").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("orderPoLabel").setAttribute("hidden", "hidden");
  window.print();
  google.script.host.close();
}
```

**Function that gets current page as a pdf and sends to server-side**

```
function savefile() {
  var element = document.getElementById("pgBody");
  var opt = {
    margin: [2, 5, 2, 5], //top, left, bottom, right
    filename: supplier + " - " + poNumber + ".pdf",
    image: {
      type: "jpeg",
      quality: 0.98,
    },
    html2canvas: {
      scale: 2,
    },
    jsPDF: {
      unit: "mm",
      orientation: "landscape",
    },
  };

  const base64File = html2pdf()
    .set(opt)
    .from(element)
    .outputPdf()
    .then(function (p) {
      google.script.run.savePdf(btoa(p), filename);
    });
}
```

**Function saving the file to a Google Drive Folder**

```
function savePdf(data){
  const file = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(data), MimeType.PDF).setName('fileName.pdf');
  DriveApp.getFolderById('folder_ID').createFile(file);
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail of `but not when called within another function?`. And, about `but it doesn't save the pdf file to the destination.`, what is `destination` in your situation?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed the modification patterns. Could you please confirm it? If those were not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Can you share the code as you have it in the documents instead of the functions separated in order to test it?

Comment: Hey, @Kessy! I do understand how crucial that would be. I even tried cleaning it up, so I could share an MRE, but the file is extensive and adapting it will be a lot of work. Killing myself trying to get it to work based on Tanaike's answer, but it doesn't throw any error, nor does this save the the d... file, as per my comment on this answer. Thanks for asking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your script, I thought that the reason for your issue might be due to that `savefile()` is run with the asynchronous process. By this, `google.script.host.close()` is run before `google.script.run.savePdf(btoa(p), filename)` is run, and your issue occurs. If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

#### Pattern 1:

```js
function savePo(user) {
  //...gets html page input data and builds a 2D array, which gets saved in a Spreadsheet
  google.script.run
    .withFailureHandler(function (e) {
      alert("The PO could not be saved./No se pudo guardar el pedido. " + e);
    })
    .savePoData(poData, poOrigin);

  savefile(); //How to run this function, which is detailed below

  //Hides Order Po Header Field and its label
  // document.getElementById("selectOrderPo").style.display = "none";
  // document.getElementById("orderPoLabel").setAttribute("hidden", "hidden");
  // window.print();
  // google.script.host.close();
}

function savefile() {
  var element = document.getElementById("pgBody");
  var opt = {
    margin: [2, 5, 2, 5], //top, left, bottom, right
    filename: supplier + " - " + poNumber + ".pdf",
    image: {
      type: "jpeg",
      quality: 0.98,
    },
    html2canvas: {
      scale: 2,
    },
    jsPDF: {
      unit: "mm",
      orientation: "landscape",
    },
  };

  const base64File = html2pdf()
    .set(opt)
    .from(element)
    .outputPdf()
    .then(function (p) {
      google.script.run.withFailureHandler(function () {
        document.getElementById("selectOrderPo").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("orderPoLabel").setAttribute("hidden", "hidden");
        window.print();
        google.script.host.close();
      }).savePdf(btoa(p), filename);
    });
}
```

#### Pattern 2:

```js
function savePo(user) {
  //...gets html page input data and builds a 2D array, which gets saved in a Spreadsheet
  google.script.run
    .withFailureHandler(function (e) {
      alert("The PO could not be saved./No se pudo guardar el pedido. " + e);
      savefile(); //How to run this function, which is detailed below
    })
    .savePoData(poData, poOrigin);
}

function savefile() {
  var element = document.getElementById("pgBody");
  var opt = {
    margin: [2, 5, 2, 5], //top, left, bottom, right
    filename: supplier + " - " + poNumber + ".pdf",
    image: {
      type: "jpeg",
      quality: 0.98,
    },
    html2canvas: {
      scale: 2,
    },
    jsPDF: {
      unit: "mm",
      orientation: "landscape",
    },
  };

  const base64File = html2pdf()
    .set(opt)
    .from(element)
    .outputPdf()
    .then(function (p) {
      google.script.run.withFailureHandler(function () {
        document.getElementById("selectOrderPo").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("orderPoLabel").setAttribute("hidden", "hidden");
        window.print();
        google.script.host.close();
      }).savePdf(btoa(p), filename);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The section within ```const base64File``` doesn't run in either pattern. I'll continue trying.

Comment: @onit Thank you for replying. About `The section within const base64File doesn't run in either pattern. I'll continue trying.`, unfortunately, I cannot replicate this. When I tested my proposed script, `google.script.host.close()` is run after `savePdf` can be run. So, in this case, it is required to know your current script for correctly replicating it. Can you provide your current script for correctly replicating it? By this, I would like to confirm it.